# trying to use sshfs on ubuntu

Tags: server, ssh, sshfs

i'm trying to use sshfs on ubuntu.  i have root access on the server i'm trying to connect to.  but everytime i try to connect using my ubuntu laptop, the message i get is the following:

```
  cp@cp-AOA150:/$ sudo sshfs root@myserver:/ /home/cp/Documents/myserverfolder/
  read: Connection reset by peer
  cp@cp-AOA150:/$
```

i'm not too familiar with ubuntu / linux but could the problem be that the key that's on the server is not for the user "cp"?
If this is the case, how do i set up the root account on ubuntu?

any suggestions would be appreciated.

btw.  i can ssh into the box no problems, but as root.  so in other words, this works:

```
  ssh root@myservername
```

i've copied over my key file from work onto this new laptop.  it's just sshfs that isn't happy right now.
thanks.

**EDIT 1**

When I run sshfs with debug options like so:

```
  cp@cp-AOA150:~$ sshfs -o sshfs_debug -p 22 root@10.14.5.182:/ /home/cp/Documents/myserverfolder/
```

I get the following error message:

```
  SSHFS version 2.4
  fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint /home/cp/Documents/myserverfolder/
  cp@cp-AOA150:~$
```

I've checked the permissions on the folder myserverfolder and it looks like this: (results of ls -la command)

```
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 19 17:11 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 cp   cp   4096 Mar 19 17:11 ..
```

**Edit 2**

I've ensured that the user cp is a part of the fuse group.

```
  cp@cp-AOA150:~$ sudo addgroup cp fuse
  [sudo] password for cp: 
  The user `cp' is already a member of `fuse'.
  cp@cp-AOA150:~$
```

**Edit 3**

Results of ls -ld

```
  cp@cp-AOA150:~$ ls -ld /home/cp/Documents/myserverfolder
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 19 17:11 /home/cp/Documents/myserverfolder
  cp@cp-AOA150:~$
```

I'm not too familiar yet with linux but i did try to create a file in this folder using vim.  I wasn't able to save the file...
I think I created the folder using the "sudo " prefix to the mkdir command... because when i try without sudo, i get a "permission denied" error message.
I'm going to google "chmod" to see how i can grant permissions to cp on this folder.

Comment: So you login with the key or with a password?

Comment: And if you run sshfs without sudo? Where did you put your key file?

Comment: Can you really write to the mountpoint? Could you try it? What's the output of `ls -ld /home/cp/Documents/cadev01` (or whatever mount point you're using now...)?

Comment: phoibos.. please check out edit 3

Comment: @dot, Is the server running OpenSSH, or an alternative such as Dropbear? This may be the problem.

Comment: camconn, yep, the server is running.  i am able to use sshfs on a different workstation against the same server...

Comment: The mount point must be writeable by the user and empty. For the sake of testing, create a new mount point `mkdir ~/mnttest` and run `sshfs -o sshfs_debug -p 22 root@10.14.5.182:/ ~/mnttest`

Comment: phoibos, can you update you answer with this last suggestion?  i'll select it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Some ideas:**

- The root account on your local system doesn't have to do anything with the account you use on the remote system. Don't run `sshfs` with `sudo`! Besides, `sshfs` is a user space file system
- Assuming you use ssh keys, did you copy your public key to the remote system? `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@myserver`
- Maybe the port for ssh is different than the standard port 22? Use the `-p` option of sshfs
- Use the debug option of sshfs: `-o sshfs_debug`
- Is login with ssh as root on the server possible at all? Some distros disable this by default.
- The user must be a member of the `fuse` group: `sudo addgroup YOUR_USER fuse`
- The mount point must be writeble by the user and empty

**Example:**

```
mkdir ~/mnttest
sshfs -o sshfs_debug -p 22 root@myserver:/ ~/mnttest
```

**Unmounting:**

```
fusermount -u ~/mnttest
```

Comment: when i run that command, i get the following error message:  SSHFS version 2.4
fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint /home/cp/Documents/myserverfolder/
cp@cp-AOA150:~$

Comment: I've updated my post to make the error message clearer.

Comment: my user is already added.  check out edit 2.

Comment: I had same problem. It turns out that in your case myserverfolder is not owned by your user cp.

Comment: When I use the command `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@myserver`, I get `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/casper/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': No such file`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In my case when sshfs did not work without a good error message, it turned out that "on the other side" there was a symbolic link pointing to another folder.

So `sshfs user@myserver:/home/user/symboliclink` does not work,
but mounting to original folder does work,
i.e. `sshfs user@myserver:/opt/realfolder`.